# Capturing PHP Response Through NSJSONSerialization

Tags: iphone, ios5, nsjsonserialization

Hi I have this code here.

```
NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[nameField text]];
        NSString *street = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[streetField text]];
        NSString *city = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[cityField text]];
        NSString *state = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[stateField text]];
        NSString *zip = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[zipField text]];
        NSString *urlToAuthPage = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"&name=%@&street=%@&city=%@&state=%@&zip=%@&lat=%@&lon=%@", name, street, city, state, zip, str1, str2];

        NSData *postData = [urlToAuthPage dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[urlToAuthPage length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://yourlink.com/poop.php"]]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        NSError *error;
        NSMutableArray *infoArray = (NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:postData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSLog(@"%@", [infoArray objectAtIndex:0]);

       if (conn) {
            UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success!" message:@"Your party has been successfully posted" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [successAlert show];
            //NSLog(conn);

            nameField.text = @"";
            streetField.text = @"";
            cityField.text = @"";
            stateField.text = @"";
            zipField.text = @"";

            [nameField resignFirstResponder];
            [streetField resignFirstResponder];
            [cityField resignFirstResponder];
            [stateField resignFirstResponder];
            [zipField resignFirstResponder];

            }
```

What I'm trying to do is get the response the server gives out that is in NSJon. I'm trying capture what is below. I've tried using an NSMutableArray to get it but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
{"status":1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that NSJSONSerialization answers witha NSDictionary, not an NSMutableArray. You can't force it to be an array, since it needs a value and a key (in this case the key is "status" and the value is "1")

Comment: Okay I changed the code a little and used NSDictionary. I'm also getting the status in the console. I'm trying to figure out how to see if it's 1 then do this and if it's not then do this but it's not working.